# Duda sobre dos errores Swift

Tags: swift

Estoy empezando con Swift y me da el siguiente error

```
//Definimos la clase
class Persona {
    //Declaramos las variables
    var nombre: String
    var apellido: String

    //Inicializamos las variables
    init (nombre: String, apellido: String){
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    }
    //Declaramos la propiedads calculada y sus métodos get y set
    var nombreApellido: String {
        get {
            return(nombre + " " + apellido)
        }
        set{
            self.nombre = newValue
            self.apellido = newValue
        }
    }
}
//Accedemos a la propiedad para definir un nombre y un apellido
var yoMisma: Persona = Persona (mombre: "Sara", apellido: "Saez") 


Aquí me da: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'mombre:apellido:', expected 'nombre:apellido:')

//Accedemos a la propiedad para leer su valor
yoMisma.nombreApellido
```

Aquí me da:

> Expression resolves to an unused property

¿Me puede ayudar alguien por favor?
Muchas gracias
Sara

Answer (score 6):

Estas utilizando el identificador ***m**ombre* cuando el esperado es ***n**ombre*.

El mensaje de error es claro, es difícil de ver, pero debes leer con cuidado:

> Incorrect argument label in call (have '**m**ombre:apellido:', expected '**n**ombre:apellido:')

Debes corregir tu código en consecuencia:

```
var yoMisma: Persona = Persona (nombre: "Sara", apellido: "Saez")
```

Finalmente, y aunque no es parte de tu duda, realmente no me hace sentido que la propiedad nombreApellido tenga un `setter`. El `getter`, 100 puntos, pero el `setter` realmente no tiene sentido.

Comment: Ahora que lo dices, tienes mucha razón
Muchas gracias jachguate voy a probar
S